# On click event dynamic object reference

Tags: delphi, dynamicobject

I create an unknown amount of labels at run time and added on click event handlers. What is the code to find out which one of the labels I clicked on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer just after posting the question :|

I needed to use (Sender as TLabel) in the on click event.

```
procedure TfrmShowing.lblShowtimesClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iCount : integer;
begin
  //Find the clicked on movie
  for iCount := 0 to Length(arrMoviePanels) do
    begin
      if arrMoviePanels[iCount] = (Sender as TLabel).Parent then
        sClickedMovie := arrMovies[iCount];
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that appropriate Tag value for every label could simplify the task.